# Endorsing Peer not signing chaincode instantiation from cli container

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

First, I am following this tutorial: 
https://github.com/CATechnologies/blockchain-tutorials/wiki/Tutorial:-Hyperledger-Fabric-v1.1-%E2%80%93-Create-a-Development-Business-Network-on-zLinux

The modifications I make, are instead of three orgs I only start one.
I am able to create and launch the docker containers, create the channel, and join the channel. I then install the chaincode, but run into an issue when I try to instantiate the chaincode. The error usually is:
Error: error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1Msp]

When I look through the docker logs for peer0.org1.example.com I come accross
2018-10-29 01:22:43.494 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 228 channel [mychannel]: MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")
I have also run this with TLS disabled in run into similiar, or the same problems.

I am able to succesfully run the samples from fabric-samples, such as fab-car, basic network, and the tuna-app example from the edX course. When doing things myself, I must be overlooking something. Any help is appreciated, even if just telling me where to go look.

I feel it is worth mentioning what I am trying to accomplish.
My goal is to be able to create a single organization, with many peers, and for now, SOLO for ordering. Any advice is welcome.

Other than changing the number of orgs, everything is followed exactly. 
I will include all the files I am using as I hope it helps.

peer-base.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=example_basic_network
        #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
```

docker-compose-base.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      #- orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053

  peer2.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer2.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.org1.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer2.org1.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer2.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
```

A bash script I use to automate
build.sh
commands run are:
./build.sh -g
./build.sh -l

```
#!/bin/bash

# define some things up here
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel

CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel




function generate_material()
{

   echo -e "======\n  Generating Crypto material \n======="
   cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml


   echo -e "======\n  Creating channel artifacts \n======="
   export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
   mkdir channel-artifacts
   configtxgen -profile NsolOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block


   echo "Should say Writing genesis block above"


   configtxgen -profile NsolChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME

   echo "Should say writing new channel tx above"

   configtxgen -profile NsolChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP

   echo "Should say writing anchor peer update above"


}

function launch_dockers()
{
   echo "Starting up docker containers"
   CHANNEL_NAME=$CHANNEL_NAME docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
   echo "going to display the containers"
   docker ps
}

function run_cli()
{
   echo "entering docker container ' cli '"
   docker exec -it cli bash   
}


function clean() 
{
   rm -rf crypto-config
   rm -rf channel-artifacts
   docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
   echo "cleaned"
   exit
}



if [ "$1" == '-c' ]; then
   clean
elif [ "$1" == '-g' ]; then
   generate_material
elif [ "$1" == '-l' ]; then
   launch_dockers
elif [ "$1" == '-t' ]; then
   run_cli
else
   echo "usage:"
   echo "-c   :   clean note, may need to run as root"
   echo "-g   :   generate materials"
   echo "-l   :   launch dockers"
   echo "-t   :   run cli with script"
fi
```

And finally the code that gets run on the cli docker container contained in a script for convenience.
cli.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# ! This script is run inside the cli container
# this script is meant to be carried over to the cli container.
# from there it will run at start up and execute the commands to create the 
# channel
cd ..
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel


#peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx

#peer channel join -b mychannel.block

#peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx 

#peer chaincode install -n chaincodez -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/

#peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n chaincodez -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member')"




peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
#
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
#
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
#
peer chaincode install -n nncc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
#
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n nncc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member')"
#

echo "FINISHED??"


# run this to keep the container alive
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your cli.sh is running inside the cli container ?

Are you sure the env path of MSP and certificate like :

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH 

CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
```

of the cli container points to the certificates of the admin or org1 ?

Comment: Yes, cli.sh is run from inside the cli docker container. I have checked inside the docker cli to make sure the env variables are set. I will go through all the dockers and verify the evn var's are set to the appropriate locations.